# Online homework systems for ordinary differential equations

Tags: online-instruction, differential-equations

What are the online homework systems for ordinary differential equations?

If you have worked with two or more systems I would like to know how you compare them for ODEs. I have heard of [WebAssign](https://www.webassign.net/), [WileyPlus](https://www.wileyplus.com/),
[MyLab](https://mlm.pearson.com/northamerica/), [WebWork](https://webwork.maa.org/), and (the build your own and share it) [Ximera](https://ximera.osu.edu/). I am familiar with WebAssign.

(a) Is there another system?

(b) If you have worked with just one homework system did you find the coverage in it adequate for the course?

(c) If you have taught ODEs out of any of the variety of texts named "Advanced Engineering Mathematics" using any online homework system I would like to hear about your experience.

Answer (score 6):

MyOpenMath is free. It doesn't look like it has a full course, but it has something, and you could add to it.

Here's what I found: Covers chapters 1-6 and 8-10 from the Trench text (Elementary Differential Equations). This is a minimal course, with only 1-5 exercises for most sections, meant to be supplemented with problems from the text.

I've been writing questions for a few courses for about a year. I have been frustrated by the inadequate documentation. But as I got more experienced, it got easier to write questions. There's a forum for asking how to do things, and my questions there have usually been answered quickly and usefully.

Answer (score 2):

For WeBWorK ODE, see: [Model Course](https://webwork.maa.org/wiki/ModelCourses/Ordinary_Differential_Equations)

Answer (score 1):

The commercial systems such as WebAssign, WileyPlus and MyLab are correlated with their textbooks and their coverage is comprehensive. If you need a lot of coverage of various topics, the price for the commercial systems may be worthwhile. You can also look into lower price options such as xyzhomework - it also has Trench questions from MyOpenMath, but they have also added some of their own.